# Rewrite the Following using $\vee,\;\wedge$, and/or $\lnot$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

1. $(p \to q) \to r$
2. $p \to (q \to r)$

This is what I've done so far:

1. $(p \to q) \to r$
   = $(p \wedge q) \vee (\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \to r$
2. $p \to (q \to r)$
   = $p \to (q \wedge r) \vee (\lnot q \wedge \lnot r)$

My understanding of this concept is quite basic so far, do I still need to manipulate the r in Q1 and the p in Q2 or am I finished?

Comment: $(1)$ take $p=0,q=1,r=0$, $(2)$ take $p=1,q=0,r=1$, will give both a counter example, so the expression is not correct.

Comment: There's more than one solution with the question posed this way.  Not sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the material implication

$$not P \;  or  \; Q $$ is equivalent  to
$$ P \; implies \; Q$$

and the negation is

$$ P \; and \; not Q$$ is equivalent to
$$ P \; does \; not\;  implies \; Q$$

Your first proposition will be

$$( p \wedge \lnot q ) \vee r$$

and the second is

$$\lnot p \vee ( \lnot q \vee r)$$